# Always logged out of Google Chrome account and websites in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, authentication

I'm using an Ubuntu Laptop connected via Wi-Fi at my workplace and a desktop Windows 10 connected via LAN at home and am experiencing a problem, that I always have to relog into my Google account. I think the problem started to occur after I recently changed my Google password. Whenever I start Chrome on the top right corner where my name is I always have a yellow triangle which looks like this

[image: Buggy]

When I click on it I get the message that  I have to authenticate again because of recent account changes. I'm getting this every time now (even though I have 2FA which I don't have to enter) and it's pretty annoying. On my working laptop I also have the problem that I'm always logged out of services such as Facebook where I always have to authenticate again (this time using 2FA) which is even more annoying. I don't have any settings that I delete my cache after a restart, nor do I disallow cookies or something like this. I'm using the default settings of Chrome. I already reinstalled Chrome but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of chrome on both machines? Please specify version numbers.

Comment: On my working laptop yes, since I just downloaded a new version. At home, I have to check, but I have auto update activated so should also be the most recent verson

Comment: Now downloading the latest version on desktop. I can only try monday if the problem still persists

Comment: and ... ? did it help? What versions do you have?